# Move expdp part file before job end

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, expdp

I have an **Oracle 11gr2** database running on **Enterprise Linux 6.6** server.

I use the following command to split the expdp dump file to 10G size chunks:

```
expdp userid=/ DIRECTORY=dmpdir dumpfile=dump%u.dmp filesize=10G schemas=user1
```

this creates 4 files that I should move to another server (rsync then rm).

Can I move a file **as soon as the expdp starts creating the following one**? and how should I do that? I have idea like while (next_file not exists) wait.

Thank you.

Comment: "and how should I do that?" Do you ask how to move a file? "I have idea like while (next_file not exists) wait." Can you explain the meaning of this  sentence, I don't understand it?

Answer (score 0):

It is not advisable to move files before the export job is finished. The reason is that when exporting, the utility "builds and maintains the master table for the duration of the job. At the end of an export job, the content of the master table is written to a file in the dump file set." (see Oracle's documentation at the following address: https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SUTIL/GUID-6BDC1CC8-8596-402D-B016-602985B97AB6.htm#SUTIL814) If you move a dump file before the job is done, you risk corrupting that process and making the job fail.

Is there a reason you need to move the files before the data pump job is finished? If not, simply wait for the job to complete. While being able to move files as soon as they are not in use would be very useful for large export/import jobs, you will save yourself a lot of time by letting the export finish before manipulating the dump files.

Answer (score 0):

There are two reasons why expdp uses more than one dump file:

- you have specified the [PARALLEL](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SUTIL/GUID-55E6AC71-5CDE-410E-AB02-798AEC54F411.htm#SUTIL858) parameter
- You have teached the limit defined by the [FILESIZE](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SUTIL/GUID-C11CA2A6-367A-40E6-A2D3-9E3775B1D4A2.htm#SUTIL848) parameter

In the latter case the description of the FILESIZE parameter in [Oracle Database, Utilities, 12c Release 1 (12.1.0.2)](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SUTIL/GUID-C11CA2A6-367A-40E6-A2D3-9E3775B1D4A2.htm#SUTIL848)says

> If the size is reached for any member of the dump file set, then that file is closed and an attempt is made to create a new file,(...)

After a file is closed, I would expect that it isn't needed anymore an can be copied, moved or deleted.

So if only one process is exporting because PARALLEL parameter is not set you can move a file to the other server after the next dump file has created.

Note: I didn't test this but deduced this from the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Even this post ist 1 year old, maybe this answer will help someone.

I faced the same problem. I had to export a 1.4 TB database but only 600 GB free space were available in the exportdirectory. So I had to move the splitted files during export.

I found out that you can move all files expect of part 01 (otherwise the export will crash). I guess it's a kind of "Masterfile" where information about the other parts are stored during export. So dont move part 01. Than you can move part 02 after part 03 is created and so on.